# Find and Replace a String in multiple .js file at once and save the file

Tags: node.js, json, terminal

I have 100 .js files with different codes in each. But they each have one line of code that is similar in all of them which is this

```
"body": `{\"pagination\",\"from\":${i},\"size\":48},date\":\"19122020\"}`
```

Now I want to run a script to replace `19122020` in all of the 100 .js files with something else (e.g. `12345678`) and then save all the 100 .js files with the new data that I replaced.

Thinking to have a .js file like `execute.js` with a script that I need help with here. And then I run in my terminal `node execute` and the result will be finding and replacing a specific string in each of the 100 .js files.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why do this in the terminal? Open any modern code editor and tell it to do that for you? VS Code, Sublime, Atom, etc. can all do this

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code and then save my codes in .js then I execute then with `node filename` .. is that what you are recommending? If so, now I need to know how to script what I described above so I can execute the script

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace : search for the pattern you need updated, and write the replacement, then apply to all files.

Comment: That is awesome! Do you want to post as answer so I accept. thanks

Comment: I do not, this is just basic editor functionality we expect in any IDE and code editor (rather than text editor) for years now, it makes far more sense to unask this question, and probably give a "what can my code editor do out of the box" a bit of a read-through =)